# Cors filter is not working on wso2 EI rest apis

Tags: angular, cors, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

We tried to invoke rest APIs from angular 5 app, the APIs are designed and deployed on EI as .car files, however, when we start the angular app, calling rest APIs fails due to `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://10.5.222.34:9763' is therefore not allowed access.`. we tried to add the CORS filter in `<EI_HOME>/conf/tomcat/web.xml` as the bellow but with no luck:

```
    <filter> 
       <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
       <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class> 
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

Can anybody help me in finding what is the problem and how to solve it?
and thank you in advance.
My code as requested is:

from the angular side is a normal HTTP POST client call, however, the browser send two request, the first one as OPTIONS to check if the server will accept the original request (the POST one) and the second is the original POST .
from the EI side:

```
<api context="/cmbassadmin/authentication" name="authentication" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="OPTIONS POST" uri-template="/login">
        <inSequence>
            <sequence key="InitiateCMBASSADMINAuthenticationSQ"/>
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" value="*"/>
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" scope="transport" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" value="*"/>
            <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
            <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
            <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
            <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
            <filter regex="OPTIONS" source="get-property('REST_METHOD')">
                <then>
                   <log>
                      <property name="message" value="in the preflight"/>
                   </log>
                   <respond/>
                </then>
                <else/>
            </filter>
            <log>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.username')" name="uri.var.username"/>
            </log>
            <call-template target="audit_trail">
                <with-param name="user_name" value="{get-property('uri.var.username')}"/>
                <with-param name="action_name" value="Login"/>
                <with-param name="description" value="Login to the xyz admin app"/>
            </call-template>
            <sequence key="AuthenticateWithIS_SQ"/>
            <loopback/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" value="*"/>
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" scope="transport" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
            <header name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" value="*"/>
            <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
            <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
            <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
            <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Did you add the following jar files to <EI HOME>/lib directory?
"cors-filter-2.4.jar" and "java-property-utils-1.9.1.jar".

Comment: yes of course @Menaka

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below properties before your send or respond mediator which sends the response back to the Angular.

```
<property name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>
<property name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
<property name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type"/>
```

You can modify the properties according to your requirements.

Comment: thank you @prabakaran, I tried to put those properties before a loopback mediator with no luck also, should be added as properties or header? thank you anyway.

Comment: You should add it to Property. Also, I have used it before Respond mediator and not loopback mediator.

Comment: thank you @prabakaran, I use it as property and headers before a respond also, and still, the same error appears.

Comment: hello @prabakaran, should I implement a rest API of method type OPTIONS for each created rest API ? or there is a generic API should be created to manage the preflight? can you please help me since I am stuck in the preflight loop a week ago with no luck. thank you

Comment: Hello @ichakkhoury I haven't created any API as OPTIONS. My APIs are POST and I just placed those Properties before issuing SEND or RESPOND. If possible, can you share your code in the question?

Comment: hello @parabakaran the code sample is added to the original question.

Comment: Is the message coming to Out sequence? Can you enable the logs and see?

Comment: Also I can see that the properties are not added as given in my answer for Headers

Comment: hello, yes the message is coming in the out sequence. what do you mean by the properties are not added as given in my answer for Headers. ?

Comment: Instead of this - <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type"/> you have used this <property name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" scope="transport" type="STRING" value="*"/>

The values for the headers are different.

Comment: and what about the OPTIONS method type, it seems that angular makes an OPTION request, before any other request. so that i implemented the options method type. is that true?

Comment: In our project, the Angular is calling the APIs in GET/POST methods only. So can't give any idea on that :(

Answer (score 0):

When we define cors filters in /conf/tomcat/web.xml, filters will be applied to the tomcat servlet port, which is 9443 by default. If you invoke your API using the passthrough transport ports(eg: 8280 and 8243 by default), required 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', etc. headers will not be present in the response. Can you try invoking your API using the servlet port?

eg: https://hostname:9443/cmbassadmin/authentication/login

Refer [this](https://medium.com/@prabushi/cross-origin-resource-sharing-for-wso2-ei-data-services-ab4aa675dd71) for more details.